# TextView Below Centered TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-relativelayout

I need to place a TextView below another TextView that is centered in parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relative_row_product"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_product"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/product" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_title_product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageview_product"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_category_product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textview_title_product"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageview_product"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:textSize="14sp" >
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

textview_category_product results in overlapping the first TextView (it seems like ignoring the centerInparent flag). How can I achieve that? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_product"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/product" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_title_product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"   
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_category_product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"   
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:textSize="14sp" >
    </TextView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relative_row_product"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp" >
```

it should be

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

instead of

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

android:layout_height="wrap_content" sets the height of your layout equal to the maximum height required by your views. IT doesn't make it fill the whole screen. So centerInParent won't center on your screen!

And also, in

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_title_product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageview_product"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

I don't think centerInParent and toRightOf should be together. Instead, use only centerInParent on your textview_title_product and use

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textview_title_product"
```

in your imageView

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relative_row_product"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_product"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/product" >
    </ImageView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_title_product"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="First TextView"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_category_product"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:text="Second TextView"
            android:textSize="14sp" >

        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```